# Logic X's synths look distorted

Tags: logic

I'm not sure if this is a legacy thing, or if I'm being stupid, but when I open the ES1/ES2 whatever in Apple Logic X, it shows me something tiny and illegible [image: horrible synth]

I'm guessing this is just cause Apple decided not to update these, but can someone confirm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what it has always looked like. It hasn't been updated for LPX.

Comment: that's sad :-( no retina!

Comment: You can resize the plugin windows, btw, although since the graphics are bitmaps it becomes blurry. Maybe better than nothing?

Comment: It's actually even harder to read than when it's tiny, it makes the pixels go all funny. It's a real shame they didn't update it with vector graphics, it makes it so much harder to use!

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the View settings in the top right (Zoom). Change to 100% and it should be ok (although  quite small on large screens). 
This has been improved on the latest versions of Logic X.